# How do I assign data-attributes to elements inside an array that allows me to remove them from both the array and the DOM?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a library app that will allow you to add books and remove books with the use of an onclick button. When I create the book it is assigned a dataset.number corresponding to the array.length - 1. I run into issues when I remove a book as next book to be added is assigned the same number as a previous element/s. Then when I try to remove a book it removes the correct from from the page but the incorrect one from the array.

```js
let myLibrary = [];

// Naming/Identifying variables for use in functions

let form = document.querySelector('#form');
let authorvalue = document.getElementById('authorValue');
let titlevalue = document.getElementById('titleValue');
let pagesvalue = document.getElementById('pagesValue');
let readvalue = document.getElementById('readValue');

// Constructor function to create new books

function Book(author, title, pages, read) {
  this.author = author;
  this.title = title;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read;
  this.info = function() {
    return `${title} by ${author} has ${pages} pages and ${read}.`
  }
}

// Function to assign data-numbers for splicing, add DOM elements and assign them values, delete button to remove DOM elements from page/array

function createBook() {
  let bookDiv = document.createElement('div', 'class=book');
  bookDiv.dataset.number = (myLibrary.length - 1);
  let titleContent = document.createElement('div');
  titleContent.classList.add('book-content');
  titleContent.innerHTML = titlevalue.value;
  let authorContent = document.createElement('div');
  authorContent.classList.add('book-content');
  authorContent.innerHTML = authorvalue.value;
  let pagesContent = document.createElement('div');
  pagesContent.classList.add('book-content')
  pagesContent.innerHTML = pagesvalue.value;
  let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
  deleteBtn.classList.add('delete');
  deleteBtn.innerHTML = 'x';
  deleteBtn.onclick = function() {
    bookDiv.remove()
    let x = bookDiv.dataset.number;
    myLibrary.splice(x, 1);
    // delete myLibrary[x];
  }
  document.querySelector('.library-main').appendChild(bookDiv);
  bookDiv.append(titleContent, authorContent, pagesContent, deleteBtn);
}

// Function to push books into myLibrary array and create DOM elements on page

function addBookToLibrary() {
  const newBook = new Book(authorvalue.value, titlevalue.value, pagesvalue.value, readvalue.value)
  myLibrary.push(newBook);
  createBook();
}

// Add form responsiveness when the submit button is pressed

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addBookToLibrary()
  form.reset();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="library-container">
    <div class="library-header">
      <div>myLibrary</div>
      <div>Login</div>
    </div>
    <div class="library-form">
      <form id="form" action="">
        <div class="author">
          <label for="author">What is the author's name?</label>
          <input type="text" id="authorValue" name="authorValue">
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <label for="title">What is the title of the book?</label>
          <input type="text" id="titleValue" name="titleValue">
        </div>
        <div class="pages">
          <label for="pages">How many pages does it have?</label>
          <input type="number" id="pagesValue" name="pagesValue">
        </div>
        <div class="read">
          <label for="read">Have you read this book?</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="readValue" name="readValue">
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Add New Book!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="library-main"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I tried making the remove book function with deleteBtn. I used myLibrary.splice(index, 1). Index(not listed above) was assigned to the books data-number. Which gave me the issue I listed above. My main issue is... How do I have the same element that is removed from the page also removed from my array? I know it's probably the assignment of the value but after being stuck for quite a bit and trying to read through documentation I feel like I'm spinning my wheels. I'm also using vanilla javascript (no Jquery).

Thank you so much in advance and as much detail as possible would be amazing. I really just want to understand the issue.

Comment: Can you provide HTML for this?

Comment: Yes! one second! I'll just edit post.

Comment: Why are you using `this` keyword in your Book function? Is this part of some class?

Comment: It will be problematic identifying the books like this because if you remove book1, then all later books will have the wrong dataset.number vs their (new) array position.  IMO use Array.findIndex to locate the book in the array by author and title, or write a custom delete handler for each deleteBtn, which knows which book it should delete.

Comment: I'd use [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as a datastore, or even [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap). When using element references as keys, it's easy to connect a JS object and DOM. In the case of WeakMap, you don't even need to take care of the removal from the JS object, the member is automatically removed when the element used as a key is removed.

Comment: @kiner_shah I'm using this keyword to assign values to properties within the object which can later be accessed through the array. This is the first project that I've done using This.

Comment: @Teemu ooooh. I haven't seen this one before I'll definitely check it out. I'll just have to wrap my head around it first!

Comment: Where is your code for deleting the book?

Comment: @kiner_shah Snippet is updated! I also tried the delete operator (commented out). delete just replaced the spot in the array with "empty" so the data numbers were still accurately removing items from the library.

Answer (score 0):

When "Delete" button is pressed press there is an event, where you can exactly know which element has been clicked and delete it (or its parent or its neighbour).

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   const element = e.target // here is your element
   // you can element.remove()
   // or element.parentElement.remove() for example}
```

Hope it helps.

Or you can get your data attribute from `e.target.dataset` then find element on the page and delete it. The id should be unique (for example, generate random string upon creation).

Comment: How do I remove it from the myLibrary array though? I believe I used the delete(index) operator and it would just fill the array spot with "empty". Is there no way to clean it up so that data attribute is reassigned when the delete button is clicked? Right now, if i click add book it assigns 0,1,2,3.... to each book created as dataset,number. And then when I remove a book it looks something like 0,1,3 while the array would read [book, book, empty, book]. I'm wanting it to instead be 0,1,2 and [book, book, book] but not sure if I'm being too nitpicky. (sorry if this is confusing)

Comment: I can't understand why do you need this myLibrary array? You're working with DOM tree, append and remove elements from there. So you always have an array of DOM elements and can get all data from there (data-attribute values, text content values, etc...) The way you want to do it is like the way modern frameworks like React do, but there is a local state which you can change and, as for me, for this situation you don't need all that.

Comment: Look at this example. Just add any random number as data-number (if you really need it for some reason) and after each adding of removing elements you can get an array of them. Just an example, hope it helps. https://codesandbox.io/s/js-add-delete-el-6v3y31?file=/src/index.js

Comment: You actually just made this make sense haha! So it's for an assignment that I'm coming back to later for TOP. Haven't yet learned anything about React. But i had the same thought as to why it's even in the first place because what I have works and seems like extra steps that don't need to be there. Array may be useful later so I'll just hold on to what I have I suppose! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Here is almost the React way (simplified), where we store all info in bookData array (so using it as a "local state"), and re-render all the elements on every modification of booksData. https://codesandbox.io/s/js-add-delete-el-2-2l4soh?file=/src/index.js